# Derivation of precession rate of a wheel gyroscope

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, torque, gyroscopes, precession

I searched on the web and all I could find is the precession rate of a spinning top. But what I want is the derivation of the precession rate of a wheel hanging from a rope, as shown below:

[image: 1]

which is taken from [this video](https://youtu.be/8H98BgRzpOM).

Professor Walter Lewin says in his [video](https://youtu.be/XPUuF_dECVI?t=1779) that
$$\omega_{\text{precession}} = \frac{\tau}{L_{\text{spin}}} $$

But the derivation is not given in that video. So it would be much appreciated if someone will give me the derivation.

Answer (score 2):

There is a more formal/mechanical way to do it, but I think this might be simple enought while being correct. There might be also a more direct way to do it.

I'll use cylindrical coordinates.

We know the torque (about the origin is) is
\begin{equation}
\vec{\tau} = \tau \, \hat{\phi}
\end{equation}
We also know, becuase it's a flat symmetric top, that the angular velocity of the body is parallel to the angular momentum of the body. Then,
\begin{equation}
\vec{L} = L \, \hat{\rho} \text{.}
\end{equation}
The relation between angular mometum and torque is
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dt} \vec{L} = \vec{\tau} \text{.}
\end{equation}
Note that the magnitude of the angular momentum is constant, since both torque and angular mometum are perpendicular for all time.
\begin{align}
L \frac{d}{dt} \hat{\rho} &= \tau \hat{\phi}  \\
L \left(\frac{d}{dt} \hat{\rho}\right) \cdot \hat{\phi}
&= \tau \\
\left(\dot{\phi}\hat{\phi}\right) \cdot \hat{\phi}
&= \frac{\tau}{L} \\
\dot{\phi} &= \frac{\tau}{L}
\end{align}
Since $\dot{\phi}$ is constant (both $\tau$ and $L$ are), we call them $\omega_{\text{precession}}$.

Comment: It seems that this is incorrect. Because direction of precessional motion is in direction of torque, but direction of precessional angular speed is perpendicular to torque and angular momentum, $\vec v=\vec\omega \times\vec r$.

Comment: Precessional angular speed $\mathbf{\omega}_{\text{press.}} \propto \hat{z}$ is perpendicular both to torque ($\hat{\phi}$) and angular momentum ($\hat{\rho}$). I understand that by ''precessional motion'' you mean $\mathbf{\omega}_{\text{press.}}  \times \mathbf{r} \propto \hat{\phi}$, in which case I agree it has the same direction than torque. I fail to see what's your point, thought. Could you point out which step you find incorrect?

Comment: You wrote above, $\tau$ is in $\hat\phi$ direction. In last two steps you derived precrssional angular speed in same direction as torque, while it is perpendicular to both torque and angular momentum.

Comment: $\tau$ is indeed in $\hat{\phi}$ direction. Last three equations are scalar equations about their magnitudes, not vectorial. I *didn't* wrote $\vec{\omega}_{\text{press.}} \propto \vec{\tau}$, if that's what you mean.

Comment: $\tau$ is in $\phi$'s direction. $L$ is in $\rho$. In direction of torque is $v$ so, $\vec\omega=\frac{v}{\rho}(\hat\rho\times \hat\phi)$. So precessional angular speed is in direction perpendicular to $\phi$ and $\rho$, that is vertical direction or $\hat z$.

Comment: Yes, I agree and I have never said otherwise. Again, last three equations are not vectorial but scalar (I took the inner product). That is, they are relating the *magnitude* of the vectorial quantity precessional angular speed with the *magnitudes* of the vectorial quantities angular momentum and torque.